# Need a way to pull data from nested entity (jasper reports)

Tags: java, hibernate, jasper-reports, javabeans

So first, I have 2 entities, first is Person, which contains:

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "SYNC_ID")
private SyncHistory syncHistory;

public SyncHistory getSyncHistory() {
    return syncHistory;
}

public void setSyncHistory(SyncHistory syncHistory) {
    this.syncHistory = syncHistory;
    }
```

and syncHistory, which contains:

```
@Column(name = "FINISH_DATE")
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Date finishDate;

public Date getFinishDate() {
    return finishDate;
}

public void setFinishDate(Date finishDate) {
    this.finishDate = finishDate;
}
```

I'm trying to reference finishDate value from my jrxml file. I've tried doing:

```
$F{nviSyncHistory}.getFinishDate()
```

but I get the following error:

```
The method getStartDate() is undefined for the type Object
```

I understand that I cannot reference the object like that. But how one would go about archiving this goal?

Answer (score 0):

So, I've solved this issue. I've changed my field in jasperreports to:

```
$F{syncHistory.finishDate}
```

and it works now.